# Error message: Coordinate index 0 is out of range for the enclosing GraphicsComplex

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, warning-messages, broken-code

I am unable understand following error message: Coordinate index 0 is out of range for the enclosing GraphicsComplex. How to fix it?

Attached data here: [pts and polygons](http://pastebin.com/9auJWKVW). See also end of question.

```
 Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon@poly], Boxed -> False]
```

returns following error :

```
 Coordinate index 0 is out of range for the enclosing GraphicsComplex.
```

Data:

```
pts={{0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 4, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {9, 8, 
  11}, {12, 13, 14}, {13, 12, 15}, {16, 17, 18}, {17, 16, 19}, {20, 
  21, 22}, {21, 20, 23}, {24, 25, 26}, {25, 24, 27}, {28, 29, 
  30}, {29, 28, 31}};

polys= {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 4, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {9, 8, 
  11}, {12, 13, 14}, {13, 12, 15}, {16, 17, 18}, {17, 16, 19}, {20, 
  21, 22}, {21, 20, 23}, {24, 25, 26}, {25, 24, 27}, {28, 29, 
  30}, {29, 28, 31}};
```

Comment: The second argument to `GraphicsComplex` should be an expression where numbers represent the corresponding point in the first argument (based on index position). Mathematica indexes starting at 1 (0 is the `Head`), so you can't refer to index 0 because it doesn't exist. Also, `Length@coord` is only 24, so you shouldn't have numbers higher than 24 in `poly`, and you shouldn't have triplets since the numbers in `poly` should be indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: this response was written before sample data for the question was changed from 24 3D points to 96 2D points.  The main message remains unchanged, however.*

The error message is complaining that the first zero in the first polygon specification is not a valid index into the list `coord` which has 24 elements.

A `GraphicsComplex` defines a list of points of interest.  Inside the `GraphicsComplex`, point specifications must take the form of an index in that list.  For example, we can draw a polygon whose corners are the first three points in `coord` like this:

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coord, Polygon@{1, 2, 3}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: graphics3d screenshot]

Note how each point specification is a simple integer, not the usual triple of coordinates.

Lists of integers are permitted, like this:

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coord, Polygon@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: graphics3d screenshot]

However, the meaning of this construct is to draw two polygons: one whose corners are the first three points from `coord` and another whose corners are the second three points.

Since `coord` has 24 elements, only the indices 1 through 24 are permissible.  In the example shown in the question, there are indices outside of this range.  The error message is complaining about the first zero in the first polygon definition.

Comment: The data has changed, but the principle is the same.  `poly` contains zero-based indices (0-95) but they must be one-based (1-96).  The simplest corrective action is something like `Graphics[GraphicsComplex[coord, Polygon[poly + 1]]]`.  However, I find it suspicious that `poly` contains degenerate polygons with coincident corners (e.g. `{0, 0, 0}` or `{1, 0, 1}`).

Comment: Well, now there is *no* data. *Now* let's see what you do!

Comment: @acl you may remove this comment, I found it useless.